# Android things keeps restarting

Tags: pi-3, android-things

Trying to install Android Things OS on RPi3 B V1.2, but before I can -- or shortly after -- I get to the set-up screen, the OS reboots. This happens repeatedly.

Rasperian works great under CPU and power load.

Tried multiple SD cards Pi boards, cables, PSUs, etc. without any improvement. However, I'm not using the official Raspberry Pi power adapter.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: One pointer is to use [another power supply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48650766/3290339)

Comment: I did (after my post), purchase an official raspberry pi power-adapter, and the same thing is still happening. I was able to install Google Things 0.4.0-preview, and everything works perfectly -- just not 1.x.x.